# How to mix 2 given student distribution with a Gaussian copula?

Tags: r, data-analysis

In `R`, I have simulated two independent student: `X1` and `X2`, with `5` and `10` `degrees of liberty` respectively. I want to consider different mixtures of these data. First, I opt for a linear mixture as `Y=RX` where `R` is as `rotation matrix`. No problem for this part.

The problem is that I want to have a `non-linear mixture of X1 and X2` by using a `Gaussian copula`.

I know that I can use the `R` `Copula` Package for simulating two student distribution with a `Gaussian copula`. But as far as I know, this package cannot solve my problem as it simulates new data and doesn't use `X1` and `X2` to create the mixture.

There is obviously something that I don't understand. Does anyone have an answer/any idea to solve the problem ? Would be great!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean mixture distribution? if so, you can use `copula` package. It provides a mixture model as well. For example,

```
Cop <- mixCopula(list(frankCopula(-5), claytonCopula(4)))
Cdat <- rCopula(500, Cop)
Res <- fitCopula(Cop, Cdat)
```

This will generate a mixture of Frank and Clayton copula. Of course, you can have a mixture of any copulas.